# org-capture: prompt for a target file

Tags: org-capture

Starting from the existing customization associated with key `j`, is there a way to view and modify the target file? In other words,

- by default, captured notes would go to `*/journal/inbox.org`,
- optionally, input a different path, say `*/journal/pc.org`.

Could you suggest ways to do that?

`~/.emacs`:

```
 '(org-capture-templates
   (quote
    (
     ("j" "Journal" entry
      (file+olp+datetree "~/Documents/write/notes/journal/inbox.org")
      "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")
     )
    )
   )
```

Manual:

- [Handling links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html)
- [Capture](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html#Capture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to write a **custom function** and use it as target: `(function function-finding-location)`. But this would get complicated.

---

Another way is to use a variable as file and then **use a wrapper** around `org-capture` to set that variable to the desired file first:

```lisp
(defvar my-org-capture-filename nil
  "File name for org capture template.")

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("j" "journal" entry (file+olp+datetree my-org-capture-filename)
         "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")))

(defun my-org-capture ()
  "Read file name to capture to."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-org-capture-filename
        (read-file-name "Capture to: " "~/Documents/write/notes/journal"
                        nil t "inbox.org"))
  (call-interactively #'org-capture))
```

Then use <kbd>M-x my-org-capture</kbd>

---

You could **create a template for each file** and use `ji`, `jp` etc. as  key to capture. To make the group work add `("j" "journal")` in the template:

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("j" "journal")
        ("ji" "inbox.org" entry
         (file+olp+datetree "~/Documents/write/notes/journal/inbox.org")
         "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")
        ("jp" "pc.org" entry
         (file+olp+datetree "~/Documents/write/notes/journal/pc.org")
         "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")))
```

Comment: I think there are several problems with the second solution: the `read-file-name` call should have the full pathname for "inbox.org" (and if that pathname starts with `~`, it should probably be wrapped in an `expand-file-name`). I still can't get it to work ("Invalid capture target specification") but even if I got it to work, having to use a different function for this template (or having all templates go through this function and answering the question every time) would be a killer for me. I much prefer the third solution: it's closer to the spirit of how I think org-capture should be used.

Comment: The "invalid capture target specification" errors I was getting were my fault: I had switched to an older version to test something and forgot to switch back.

Comment: @NickD `expand-file-name` is already done inside `read-file-name` respectively `read-file-name-default`. Adapted the function call to use `initial` instead of `default-filename` to not have to use the full path.

Comment: First sol works like a charm. Got rid of `%i %a`, since linking to the file:header from where the capture was called not always warranted. If it is, I use `M-x org-store-link`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick that works for me is to use `buffer-file-name` as the filename target. Applied to your example that would be:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("j" "Journal" entry (file+olp+datetree buffer-file-name)
         "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")))
```

In the case of such a template, my workflow is to switch first to the target orgfile, and then to invoke the template.