# Capture at an arbitrary date

Tags: org-capture, org-refile

In this example I changed the date for `Entered` to 12/07/2019 at the capture editing stage. Yet it gets filed under today's date. How can file it under the right date, that is 12/07/2019? Ideally in one step. But if not, the obvious additional steps would be 1/ create a headline for 12/07/2019, and its parents. 2/ `org-refile` under the hl created in 1/. How to do 1/?

[image: org-capture]
[image]

PS: I'm using a variant of the capture proposed [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54086/org-capture-prompt-for-a-target-file):

```
(defun my-org-capture ()
  "Read file name to capture to."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-org-capture-filename
        (read-file-name "Capture to: " "~/Documents/write/notes/journal"
                        "inbox.org" t))
  (call-interactively #'org-capture))
```

Answer (score 1):

The capture template you linked to is the key here:

```
 ("j" "Journal" entry
      (file+olp+datetree "~/Documents/write/notes/journal/inbox.org")
      "* %?
Entered on %U
  %i
  %a")
```

The date you are modifying is in the content of the entry: the `%U` gets replaced with the current timestamp which you are then modifying.

However the 'file+olp+datetree' target defines where the entry will actually go, and in this case the default for a datetree is to add a heading for today's date. That heading is not related to the content of the entry that you are editing.

What you want here is to override the default behavior of datetree. If you always want to be prompted, add the optional `:time-prompt` property to your capture template. If most of the time the default behavior is what you want, you can leave the template as-is and instead use a `C-1` prefix to trigger the prompt.

From the Org [Template elements](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html) documentation:

> ```
>  ‘:time-prompt’
>       Prompt for a date/time to be used for date/week trees and when
>       filling the template.  Without this property, capture uses the
>       current date and time.  Even if this property has not been
>       set, you can force the same behavior by calling ‘org-capture’
>       with a ‘C-1’ prefix argument.
> ```

Comment: The `C-1 C-c j` worked, thanks. How about the rest of the question? "1/ create a headline for 12/07/2019, and its parents."